# How to use munin ping_ plugin to track packetloss

Tags: munin

`ping_` does not provide any graph (`graph no` in config) but it provides value, that could be used to trigger critical and warning levels.

In `munin.conf` I have `ping_.packetloss.warning 20` and in plugin config I also have `env.packetloss_warn 20`

My network cable is disconnected.

Running `fetch ping_` while connected to node on this host I am getting `packetloss.value 100`

But after 5 minutes and after running `munin-cron` manually I see no warning generated in webpage.

I have `ping_` graph there, but no warning about packetloss.
What should I do?

--

I just found that nothing is saved in rrd file if `graph no`. So, I commented it out and now I have data in rrd (`rrdtool fetch ...`) and `munin-limits` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like I misunderstood Munin.

First of all, "Problems" section has nothing to do with `munin-limits`. It only displays for graphs, and `munin-limits` sends info to email. nagios etc.

`munin-limits` uses `critical` and `warning` sections of plugin, and there is a mistake in manual: https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/pull/113

So, If you have no graph nor critical/warning config nothing is saved.

That means you can get email when packetloss == 100, but you can't see in on graph unless you comment out `graph none``, and that should be fixed I assume.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty versions of ping_ around.

https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/all/munin-plugins-core/2.0.19-3/file/usr/share/munin/plugins/ping_

Just change line 83 into
echo 'packetloss.graph yes'

The intention of the dev is to allow generating warning emails without doubling the weight of the visual image.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin does the job for me:
https://gallery.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/munin-contrib/ping/
https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/blob/master/plugins/ping/ping
(same source)

Create one plugin called ping for times, and one called ping_packetloss for loss; then enter your targets in /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node and reload.

Times are shown on a 0-0.15 s scale, while loss is 0-100%; they make seperate graphs because 0.05s is not visible on a 0-100 graph.